# Winform: Radio button logic with another look and feel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I need to implement a radio button logic(multiple possibilities, one choice) with another look and feel.

The look and feel should be similar to this:
[image]

Meaning: an image, a title and a small description, no radio button but a border for the selected one.

I want to know if you know any existing components that can do this(in c# or in devexpress library) or if I have to implement this myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a list view, not a radio box. See MSDN help [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx).

View.Details enumeration:

> Each item appears on a separate line with further information about each item arranged in columns. The left-most column contains a small icon and label, and subsequent columns contain sub items as specified by the application. A column displays a header which can display a caption for the column. The user can resize each column at run time.

View.Tile enumeration

> Each item appears as a full-sized icon with the item label and subitem information to the right of it. The subitem information that appears is specified by the application. This view is available only on Windows XP and the Windows Server 2003 family. On earlier operating systems, this value is ignored and the ListView control displays in the LargeIcon view.

Comment: Hi @David , thank you for your response. In my case, the `Tile` is the closest view that I could use with ListView, and they doesn't allow me to have a description, right?

Comment: You mean the top blue-color words "What type of... "?

Comment: I mean the "my first data source description with multiline text"

Comment: "the item label and subitem information to the right of it", you should use item label for that purpose.

Comment: I made some tests: First I really need to have the displayed layout(one title in bold, and a multiline text above), and the MSDN specify "on the right". Secondly: I've tested to create a list view, with one item that has only one subitem with a small text, but this subitem text isn't displayed

Comment: see this post http://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/04/04/spotlight-on-the-listview-control-part-1/

Comment: If you really want to mimic exact visual result, WPF is your choice, rather than winform!

Answer (score 0):

With RadioButton you can set Appearance=Button, use also Image property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way to add a description with a different police above the title?

Comment: If you want two different colors/fonts in text you must override OnPaint or handle Paint event of RadioButton.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the DevExpress SimpleButton components that could do such behavior